# bit vector range selection with runtime value in system verilog

Tags: logic, verilog, digital, system-verilog

Let's say I have a vector `value[6:0]` and an input vector `input[3:0]`. The problem is I want to set a number of bit in value vector to 1 base on value of input, e.g.:

`input = 0011` (3 in dec) then `value = 000111` (set 3 bits to `1`)
`input = 0101` (5 in dec) then `value = 011111` (set 5 bits to `1`)

As we can do this easy only when the value in constant, but here it is run-time change. Any ideas on solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no need to select a range here.

```
wire [3:0] input;
wire [7:0] shifted;
wire [6:0] value; //This can only hold 0 to 7

//Assign 2^input then subtract 1
assign shifted = 1'b1 << input;
assign value = shifted - 1;
```

Comment: thanks Adam, I will try this way, I did another way use for loop. Maybe will try to see which ways save me resources. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

This could be as simple as this:

```
wire [3:0] input;
wire [31:0] constant_value = 32'h0000_FFFF;
wire [15:0] output;

assign output = constant_value[ input +: 16 ];
```

Note "+:" range selection.

Comment: `assign output = constant_value[ 0 +: input ];` , will it give me correct output?